# Abandoning a covenant

Tags: dark-souls-2

Suppose I join a covenant and I then want to switch to another one. What happens if you decide to abandon a covenant? Do you receive any malus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Dark Souls 2 Collector's Edition guide, p 419:

> Leaving a Covenant in Dark Souls II will neither decrease your rank nor increase your Sin count, and you can rejoin at any time with the same level of prestige you had when you left.

Comment: Do you only keep you rank or do you also keep your progress towards the next rank (e.g. having offered 5 of the required 10 snlight medals).

Comment: You keep your current rank and progress. Basically, you can hop between covenants at will with absolutely zero penalty whatsoever.

Comment: What is the benefit for abandoning covenants through Sweet Shalquoir then?